# Do event after PropertyChanged Event is done

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, properties, flags

I am trying to do a "Clear Flag" in my code. I have data being shown on the UI continuously, and I want the user to be able to clear the data when the code is running with a "Clear" button. I have a second thread collecting and updating the data on the UI Thread. I tried to use a flag in the properties that when it sees the "Clear Flag" is true to rests to a predetermined value. When the clear button is pressed I set my "Clear Flag" to true and it clears the data, but my problem is knowing when it is done and setting the "Clear Flag" back to false when it is done.

```
private bool _clear;
public bool Clear
{
    get
    {
        return _clear;
    }
    set
    {
        _clear = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Clear");

        if (value)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty);
        }
    }
}

private int _motorRPM;
public int MotorRPM
{
    get
    {
        return _motorRPM;
    }
    set
    {
        _motorRPM = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MotorRPM");
    }
}


private int _aveRPM;
public int AveRPM
{
    get
    {
        return _aveRPM;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Clear)
        {
            _aveRPM = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _aveRPM = (_aveRPM + value) / 2;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("AveRPM");
    }
}


private int _minRPM = Int32.MaxValue;
public int MinRPM
{
    get
    {
        return _minRPM;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Clear)
        {
            _minRPM = Int32.MaxValue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value < _minRPM)
            {
                _minRPM = value;
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("MinRPM");
    }
}


private int _maxRPM;
public int MaxRPM
{
    get
    {
        return _maxRPM;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Clear)
        {
            _maxRPM = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value > _maxRPM)
            {
                _maxRPM = value;
            }
         }
         OnPropertyChanged("MaxRPM");
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a "Clear" Property that when set to true will call an update all properties with OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty) with each property resting to a known value when "Clear" is true.

How do I set Clear back to false when all PropertyChanged events are done?

Comment: Huh? Do `Clear = false;` just as I guess you did `clear = true` to set it... Or is your code missing some vital part/info?

Comment: Ah. Sorry, misunderstood you :) To me, you are kind of abusing the property changed mechanism. Why don't you use a single command and let it reset all properties and have each property handle its own PropertyChanged instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said Niclas, I would said: do not do it like this! The purpose of the PropertyChanged in your ViewModel is to update the UI. If you had some sort of logic depending of your propertychanged, it will be a nightmare to debug!

Keep your property as clean as possible. Now to update some dependent value it would be better to do something like this:

```
private bool _clear;
public bool Clear
{
    get
    {
        return _clear;
    }
    set
    {
        _clear = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Clear");

        if (_clear)
          ClearValues();
    }
}

public void ClearValues()
{
   AveRPM=0;
   MinRPM=0;
   MaxRPM=0;
   ...
   Clear=False;
}
```

Not perfect but seems much more readable and maintainable to me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You know what you guys are right. Since I have a button bound command calling a function that sets Clear to true, I am going to get rid of Clear and put my ClearValues() there. Thank you.

Comment: This works thank you for the help, but I did it a little different. Instead of AveRPM = 0, I set _aveRPM = 0, since I have the math in property. Other than that, thank you. Just ignore what I put before. It wouldn't let me edit it.